# Back Propagation Weight Adjustment function not working

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm creating a neural network using a sigmoid activation function and my weight adjusting function is not working. Weights are randomly initialized from -1 to 1 and as the network trains the values are getting out of range.

Weights are stored in an adjacency matrix and each weight is adjusted with a loop and this formula my professor gave me to calculate the change in the weight(deltaW). When deltaW is added to the current weight I tried making it negative because my prof suggested trying that but there was no such luck. I have tested all other functions and they work fine so my issue must lie in here.

```
void adjustWeights(struct neuralNetwork* network_ptr, struct dataSet data){
    float stepsize = 0.1,
        summation = 0,
        deltaW = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){//adjust weights between intermediate and output
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
           deltaW =stepsize*(network_ptr->outputNodes[i] - data.target[i]) * network_ptr->outputNodes[i]* (1 -network_ptr->outputNodes[i]) * network_ptr->intermediateNodes[j];
            //cout << "weight: " << network_ptr->intermediateToOutput[j][i] << "  deltaW:  " << deltaW;
            network_ptr->intermediateToOutput[j][i] += deltaW;
            //cout << "  new weight: " << network_ptr->intermediateToOutput[j][i] << endl;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3; i++){ //adjust weights between input and intermediate
        for(int j=0;j<3; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<2; k++)//this does the summation portion of the weight adjusment.
                summation =(network_ptr->outputNodes[k] - data.target[k]) * network_ptr->outputNodes[k]* (1 -network_ptr->outputNodes[k]) * network_ptr->intermediateNodes[j]*network_ptr->intermediateToOutput[j][k]
                            * network_ptr->intermediateNodes[j]* (1- network_ptr->intermediateNodes[j]) * network_ptr->inputNodes[i];
                network_ptr->inputToIntermediate[i][j] += stepsize*summation;
        }
    }
}
```

As the weights are adjusted they just keep growing for some reason. One time I ran it and a weight got up to 7.8.
I sent the entire project to my Prof and He said everything appears to be correct. So I am completely dumbfounded.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated: consider passing `data` in as a `const` reference, `const dataSet & data`, to prevent an avoidable copy. Also note that C++ is smart. It knows that a `struct` is a `struct`, so you don't have to keep telling it.

Comment: Recommendation: chop up some of those jumbo lines into multiple computations. You can more easily snoop in on what is happening with a debugger or print statements. If you are worried about performance, don't. Compile with optimizations on and all the stuff you did to make the code easier to fit in the human brain will be packed into an even tighter form of high-speed illegibility. Keep the code easy on you and let the compiler turn it into computer-gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Line 10:

```
network_ptr->intermediateToOutput[j][i] += deltaW;
```

should be `[i][j]` instead.

Comment: That sadly did not work either. It made the weights max out around 14 and 15 now.

Comment: @AlexCrim can you edit the question to include the definitions for neuralNetwork and dataSet?